# Braintree php api sets cart detail for a transaction

Tags: php, braintree

Is there any way to put my cart detail to a transaction so I can view the information at braintree transaction report?
Example my cart:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [reference] => Ordernumber
        [name] => 1234
        [quantity] => 1
        [unit_price] => 37100
        [discount_rate] => 0
        [tax_rate] => 60%
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [reference] => Addon
        [name] => dinner
        [quantity] => 1
        [unit_price] => 37100
        [discount_rate] => 0
        [tax_rate] => 60%
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

You can perform your own [custom reporting](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/reports/custom/php) so that you can customize your reports to exactly meet your needs.

There are ways to store information about transactions in our Gateway such as using [customFields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php#custom_fields), but we suggest that you store your business logic data in your own systems and retrieve the relevant data from Braintree when you wish to generate a report.

Comment: Thanks, I has asked braintree tech support and they say that we just have only way to do that is creating a fake cart by customFields parameter.